# react-dom.development.js?61bb:88 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `small`

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am receiving this warning:

`` react-dom.development.js?61bb:88 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute 'small'. ``

for this jsx:

```
        <Button small>Small </Button>
```

with this component definition:

```
import React from 'react';
import { baseComponentProps } from '../DesignComponentUtils';
export default function Button({ children, small, secondary, ...props }) {
  return (
    <button
      {...baseComponentProps({
        initialClass: 'design-button',
        addableClasses: ['small', 'secondary'],
        props: { small, secondary, ...props },
      })}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

I would like to be able to make my own attributes for Button that don't have to be set to values, but just become true or false if they are added to the use of the component so that the JSX is less verbose.

Is there a way to achieve this without triggering this warning.

Update:

I want it to be a boolean and JSX is performing this correctly, but it is throwing an unwanted warning. I would like to not get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

If a prop is provided in JSX but does not include a value:

```
<Button small>Small</Button>
```

the value of that prop becomes true. JSX will automatically convert it to a boolean. I'm not aware of a way to bypass that behavior. [Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true)

I might instead suggest using an enumeration with a default value instead of a "flag". Maybe something like `size={"small"|"medium"|"large"}` that defaults to `"medium"`.

Comment: I want it to be a boolean. JSX is performing correctly, but it is throwing an unwanted warning. I would like to not get the warning.

Comment: If you inspect the DOM, does the `small` get added as an attribute to the HTML?